# How to import Windows' recent files into the Unity "Recent Files" list?

Tags: unity, windows, zeitgeist

I had an idea to create a script that will auto-run on startup to import the recent files list from Windows into Ubuntu's Unity recent-files list.

I don't know anything about how Unity stores that information for its recent files but I do know that in Windows, the recent files info is stored in a folder called "Recent" as a bunch of `.ink` files with the names of the files used.

What I would like to do is create a script or maybe later on a small program with a GUI for selecting the Windows recent directory for the desired user account.

How would this work?

Answer (score 0):

Zeitgeist stores it data in a SQLite DB located at ~/.local/share/zeitgeist/activity.sqlite
But you shouldn't really try to add entries directly. You'd be better of using the API: http://zeitgeist-project.com/docs/0.3.1/dbus_api.html

Assuming that you have straight access to the partition that windows is on (i.e. it is mounted and readable, etc.) "all" you need to do then is read out the lnk files and add an entry for each.

You'll probably find that the hard parts are

1) Parsing the lnk file from linux ( http://sourceforge.net/projects/jafat/files/lnk-parse/ might be a good place to start)
2) Adding entries the correct way.

Hope this helps.